Can my charger handle this?
I am trying to put 230 V dc on the ISDT 608dp charger for my FPV drone batteries (I don't know if this is the right form). This is the link: ISDT 608DP. Can my charger handle this? AI says it can but the input dc voltage for the charger is 5-30 V, but can it still work?

the symbol for voltage is an upper case V ... include a space, as in 230 V

it is unclear what you are saying ... for example, what does this mean? Can my charger handle this AI

You know the answer.  Define range.  As in, an input voltage range of 5-30V.

Stop asking engineering questions to AI if you dont know the field well enough to quality check the answer!

No, don't do this.
A device designed to accept 5 to 30 V DC will not survive 230 V DC applied to its input - unless the engineers considered that situation. They might have considered reverse polarity and some range of input voltage but over 7 times the designed max input is unlikely.
